# why client connections appear as established when connection is not accepted yet

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket, linux-mint

I was trying to reproduce a situation when a server is heavily loaded, there should be a few connections in status, SYN_SENT as visualized through netcat.

i have created a server socket and opened ten connections from netcat; i assumed they would show up in netstat as SYN_SENT but then with tcpdump, it looks like kernel sends syn-ack and the client responds with ack and tcp handshake is completed and they are all ESTABLISHED.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;

public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(9999);
        Thread.currentThread().join();
    }
}
```

so the `serversocket.accept` does not play an any role in connection establishment (deciding whether `syn.ack` should be sent) rather it waits for the OS/kernel to assign an io handle for that socket? Is this behavior consistent across different OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the connection *is* established. Calling accept() isn't a pre-requisite for that. The system accepts incoming connections and enqueues them to the backlog queue. Calling accept() just removes an item from the queue, blocking while it is empty.

Comment: The accept() call takes a backlog as a param. This input determines the maximum number of pending TCP connections that are allowed. So, if you are dealing with a large number of connections, then please make sure that you specify a large backlog limit to accept() call. Please note that the underlying OS can also have its own limit. FOr example, Linux has its own max limit of connections (256, I think) and so if you specify a backlog of more than 256,then Linux would not take that and instead use the max limit of 256.

Comment: @ManojPandey The *listen()* call takes a backlog as a parameter. The platform can vary what you specified, up or down, and there is no way to discover whether it did so, or what the effective value is. It seems to me that this should have been an answer to the question, not a comment on this answer.

Comment: Well, I liked your answer first (hence, upvoted it!), so I thought adding details about the backlog would be a nice piece of additional info to your answer!. I agree, the max limit provided by listen() can be surprising and as a programmer, especially when writing connection-intensive apps, one needs to be aware of that.

Comment: that was a typo: you are right, it is the listen() call that takes a backlog and not accept()..  For connections that are dropped due to the backlog limit, the saving grace is that TCP is designed to handle this. When the server ignores a SYN becuase the backlog is reached, then it simply drops the SYN packet and doesnot send a RST -- this way, the client can retry later and send another SYN. Hopefully, by that time the backlog would have been reduced.

Comment: @ManojPandey That's platform-dependent. Windows sends an RST when the backlog is full. Unix and Linux behave as you describe.

Answer (score 0):

SYN_SENT exists on a lower level on the network stack than what you use here. You will probably have better results using a network packet crafting tool to spoof the connection parts that you require.